# How to credit an artist for adding minor details to a vehicle?

Tags: technical-writing, legal

How do you credit someone for coming up with a general design of a vehicle without designing every little aspect about it? Let's say you make a video and you want to credit the person who came up with the general design of a vehicle while also crediting the artist for putting in his own little touches.

I want to credit the artist for their effort to add details, how do you do that in the credit portion of the video? What particular terms should you use and do you need to add some additional information or not?

Answer (score 1):

"With contributions from..."
‐---------
'Contributions' is a good word to use to indicate that a person made notable contributions to a project without being a vital part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

What did they actually DO?
You can credit that.

Were they a manager?  Credit them for that aspect.

Was this a SYSTEMS design concept  done before detailed design.
You could credit them for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In the credits section, just separately credit both people.

Credit the person who came up with the general design with a credit line and separately credit the person who thought up the more minor details by giving them a credit line specifically mentioning exactly which things they were responsible for.